# how to upload just my changes in case I have downloaded patch set from other contributors

Tags: git, version-control, gerrit

I have downloaded changes from other developers, these are required for my development work. But even their changes are not yet on the main branch, just changes hosted in Gerrit. Now, after downloading their changes and making my changes on top of theirs when I try to do a upload, git tries to upload even their patch set as well with my changes. Their changes show up in my git log after download.

How can I just upload my changes?

Comment: Are the changes you made in a separate branch? And what you mean with "try to do a upload"? `git push` or `git merge`?

Comment: I downloaded the main branch, hard reset it to a known commit hash that other have also used to create their patchsets and then I downloaded their changes, then I made my changes and now I try a git push

Comment: Are the changes from other developers integrated in a branch or still under review? You need to specify which commands you've used to "download their changes".

Comment: Their changes are not integrated yet, I have used git fetch

Answer (score 0):

- try to checkout the patchset of others. (there is a link in gerrit)
- make modifications on the files
- amend the changes (`git commit --amend`)
- push the new patchet to review (`git push origin HEAD:refs/for/<branch_id>`)